# Get robocopy to copy completely silently

Tags: robocopy, silent

Is it possible to run robocopy in some sort of "completely silent" mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any command-line utility can be made completely silent by redirecting stdout and stderr to the special file 'nul'. This is Windows' equivalent to /dev/null on *nix systems.

```
command >nul (stdout is not echoed)

command 2>nul (stderr is not echoed)

command >nul 2>&1 (neither stdout nor stderr is echoed)
```

The latter is the one you want to make it completely silent.

Comment: `>nul`is batch syntax and not valid for powershell... Use `>$null` instead. (Applies, if robocopy is triggered from PS rather than BAT)